# How to check whether an android device is capable of haptic feedback?

Tags: android

On some devices, the .performHapticFeedback fails silently, there is no way to know whether the haptic feedback succeeded or not, on such a device, the haptic feedback setting is true

Is there a way to know whether the device is capable of haptic feedback, or whether the haptic feedback executed?

(The device is a Galaxy W with android2.3 that I use for testing, I don't think it's capable of haptic feedback, as there is no haptic feedback setting)

Answer (score 1):

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

You can use following API. Added in API level 11. No permission required.

```
boolean isVibrator = mVibrator.hasVibrator();
```

It checks whether the hardware has a vibrator or not.

If you want to vibrate device according to support, you need to add permission. `android.permission.VIBRATE` and then call `mVibrator.vibrate(long millisenonds)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know too much about the android dynamics, yet vibration and haptic feedback seems to be different things, the device in question can vibrate, yet there seems to be no native haptic feedback feature (I mean it theoretically can provide haptic feedback, but the .performHapticFeedback method does nothing)

Comment: @KaanSoral performHapticFeedback() API won't work if haptic is not enabled. You can check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback(int)

To check user's haptic setting use following line
Settings.System.getInt(Context.getContentResolver(),                                    
                       Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0);

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, the haptic feedback setting seems to be enabled - as far as I understand, that's just a setting that's enabled by default, being enabled doesn't mean that the capability/integration exists

Answer (score -1):

My educated guess would be the following:

In your activity/service code try to check if the vibrator service is available like this:

```
  // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
if(v == null){
//no haptic feedback is possible
}
else{
//haptic feedback is a possible feature
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I also replied to @Anupam's answer, I think haptic feedback and vibration are different things, haptic feedback seems to be a specific and native usage of the vibration motor

Comment: A device can have a `Vibrator` and not support haptic feedback.

Comment: yah im not sure but, could you recommend how it would be done. i was thinking this is the closest way